# questions about PacketAcknowledgements in nesC,TinyOS

Tags: c, tinyos, nesc

In order to learn how to use the interface **PacketAcknowledgements**,i try to modify the example in apps/RadioCountToLeds,but there are some problem,the transmit of data can't be done and it seems there is no ack back to the sender.

the file RadioCountToLedsC is as follows:

```
#include "Timer.h"
#include "RadioCountToLeds.h"


module RadioCountToLedsC @safe() {
  uses {
    interface Leds;
    interface Boot;
    interface Receive;
    interface AMSend;
    interface Timer<TMilli> as MilliTimer;
    interface SplitControl as AMControl;
    interface Packet;
    interface PacketAcknowledgements;
    interface AMPacket;
  }
}
implementation {

  message_t  packet;

  bool locked = FALSE;
  uint16_t counter = 0;

  event void Boot.booted() {
    dbg("Boot","Application booted.\n");
    call AMControl.start();
  }

  event void AMControl.startDone(error_t err) {
    if (err == SUCCESS) {
    if(TOS_NODE_ID==0)
    {
      call MilliTimer.startPeriodic(1000);
    }
    }
    else {
      call AMControl.start();
    }
  }

  event void AMControl.stopDone(error_t err) {
    // do nothing
  }

  event void MilliTimer.fired() {
    counter++;

     dbg("RadioCountToLedsC", "RadioCountToLedsC: timer fired, counter is %hu.\n", counter);

    if (locked==TRUE) {
      return;
    }
    else {
              radio_count_msg_t* rcm = (radio_count_msg_t*)call Packet.getPayload(&packet, sizeof(radio_count_msg_t));
          if (rcm == NULL) {
        return;
          }

          rcm->counter = counter;
          call PacketAcknowledgements.requestAck(&packet);
          if (call AMSend.send(AM_BROADCAST_ADDR, &packet, sizeof(radio_count_msg_t)) == SUCCESS) {
        dbg("RadioCountToLedsC", "RadioCountToLedsC: packet sent.\n", counter); 
        locked = TRUE;
          }
      }

  }

  event message_t* Receive.receive(message_t* bufPtr, void* payload, uint8_t len) {
    if (len != sizeof(radio_count_msg_t)) {return bufPtr;}
    else {
      radio_count_msg_t* rcm = (radio_count_msg_t*)payload;
        dbg("RadioCountToLedsC", "Received packet of counter %u.\n", rcm->counter);
      if (rcm->counter & 0x1) {
    call Leds.led0On();
      }
      else {
    call Leds.led0Off();
      }
      if (rcm->counter & 0x2) {
    call Leds.led1On();
      }
      else {
    call Leds.led1Off();
      }
      if (rcm->counter & 0x4) {
    call Leds.led2On();
      }
      else {
    call Leds.led2Off();
      }
      return bufPtr;
    }
  }

  event void AMSend.sendDone(message_t* bufPtr, error_t error) {
    if(call PacketAcknowledgements.wasAcked(bufPtr)){
        dbg("RadioCountToLedsC", "ACKED!\n");
        locked = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        dbg("RadioCountToLedsC", "NOT ACKED!\n");
    }
  }

}
```

i want to know where the error is.
by the way,can anyone give me an example about how to use the interface  **PacketAcknowledgements**?
thanks very much.

the configuration file are as follows:

```
configuration RadioCountToLedsAppC {}
implementation {
  components MainC, RadioCountToLedsC as App, LedsC;
  components new AMSenderC(AM_RADIO_COUNT_MSG);
  components new AMReceiverC(AM_RADIO_COUNT_MSG);
  components new TimerMilliC();
  components ActiveMessageC;

  App.Boot -> MainC.Boot;
  App.PacketAcknowledgements ->AMSenderC.Acks;
  App.Receive -> AMReceiverC;
  App.AMSend -> AMSenderC;
  App.AMControl -> ActiveMessageC;
  App.Leds -> LedsC;
  App.MilliTimer -> TimerMilliC;
  App.Packet -> AMSenderC;
  App.AMPacket ->ActiveMessageC;
}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but there are [some questions on TinyOS mailing list](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=packetacknowledgements+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fmail.millennium.berkeley.edu%2Fpipermail%2Ftinyos-help) which discuss PacketAcknowledgements

Comment: @ybk1996 What particular error message are you getting? Can you please also post the configuration file (i.e RadioCountToLedsAppC) so we can see how you are wiring the PacketAcknowledgement interface.

Comment: i have posted the configuraton file...and by the way i think my question has been solved,while i call PacketAcknowledgements.wasAcked(bufPtr),if it has  been acked the result of it is 0,not 1.